# Is there a way to fetch the user's work history using facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

As of April 4, 2018, Facebook's Graph API has deprecated a few of its fields, including the work history, and the friend lists of a particular user.

Is there a different way to fetch these data?

Comment: No, there is not. (If Facebook wanted you to still have access to this data, they would probably not have deprecated those, or announced what their replacements are at the same time.)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Also, I am working on the LinkedIn API as well and I'm facing some issues. I am able to generate the authorization code, but not able to retrieve the access token. Could you help me out?